# AVAudioPlayer not playing mp3 sound

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, spotify

I am trying to play a 30 second preview of a Spotify song using AVAudioPlayer. The url to the mp3 file looks like this: https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/4f5fa753f8e814c51c718bf34bbc594bf55ef5b2

Here is my code to play this song:

```
trackObj.previewURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/4f5fa753f8e814c51c718bf34bbc594bf55ef5b2")
// set up the audio player
if trackObj.previewURL != nil {
    do {
        try previewPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: trackObj.previewURL)
        previewPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        previewPlayer.play()
    } catch _ {}
}
```

This does not do anything. The song does not begin to play at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
   var aSongURL: String = String(format: " https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/4f5fa753f8e814c51c718bf34bbc594bf55ef5b2")
        // NSLog(@"Song URL : %@", aSongURL);
    var aPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: aSongURL)!)
    var anAudioStreamer: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: aPlayerItem)
    anAudioStreamer.play()
```

Avoid syntax mistake if any because i have type here

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 4):

AVAudioPlayer is not for remote URLs. Use AVPlayer instead.